# My app does not listen ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I noticed when App is updated, Intents all disappear, so I need this app to listen to App update and re-send the intents, like it does with BOOT_COMPLETE

AndroidManifest.xml

```
       <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
    public class AlarmReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private AlarmDB pAlarms;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int reqCode = intent.getIntExtra("requestCode", 0);
        System.out.println("Received code:" + reqCode);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        pAlarms= new AlarmDB();
        pLoadAlarms(context);
        System.out.println("Received Signal:" + intent.getAction());
        if(Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            System.out.println("Replaceing Packing");
            for(int i=0;i<pAlarms.getSize();i++){
                if(pAlarms.get(i).enabled){
                    setAlarm(context,pAlarms.get(i));}
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

And I tested ACTION with adb shell

```
C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb shell am broadcast -a ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
Broadcasting: Intent { act=ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

But on Logcat it does not print anything in the code, so I assume no signal was even received.

Still, if I change versionCode at gradle and update app through android studio, all the Broadcast signals disappear and MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is not called/received.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED Is a protected Intent and can only be sent by the system. So ADB won't work. Perhaps Android Studio is stopping the process before install. Try sideloading the newer version APK perhaps to confirm if it is working or not.